# warning: invalid credential line: [0x7FFEF7EABC10] ANOMALY: meaningless REX prefix used?

Tags: node.js, azure, sails.js

I'm following this guide: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-nodejs-sails-cli-nodejs

I'm getting this error when i try to

```
 git push azure master
```

Error:
warning: invalid credential line: [0x7FFEF7EABC10] ANOMALY: meaningless REX prefix 
used?

What is exactly happening?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a Web Apps application directly on Azure Portal, and set some configurations on portal and your local project, to instead of the Step 2 of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-nodejs-sails-cli-nodejs.

1. Create a Web Apps application on Azure portal
   [image]
2. Modify the user\passwd for your git deployment credential.
   [image]
3. Set the Deployment options to `Local Git`
   [image]
4. Configure your local project as Step 3 at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-nodejs-sails-cli-nodejs
5. Deploy to Azure via Git.

It works fine on my side.

Answer (score 0):

The error code when converted to ASCII is showing up as "þ÷ê¼" 
It could point to a problem with the credentials you used in the earlier step2.3